# PHP: insert NULL if input value is empty

Tags: php

i have been trying to insert *NULL* to my database if the value of input is empty
but i still it insert `empty and NULL string`

Here's my code

this code returns blank

```
  if (empty($_POST['caller'])){ $caller= NULL; }else{ $caller =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['caller']);}

  or this

  $caller =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['caller']);
  $caller = !empty($caller_contact) ? "'$caller'" : NULL;
```

this code returns NULL string

```
  $caller =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['caller']);
  $caller = !empty($caller_contact) ? "'$caller'" : 'NULL';

 or this

  if (empty($_POST['caller'])){ $caller= 'NULL'; }else{ $caller =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['caller']);}
```

query

```
$sql_caller = "INSERT INTO `tblcall_info` VALUES ('','$save_inc_id','$call_time','$call_date','$caller','$caller_contact','$receiver','$device')";
```

i have also tried changing `'$caller'` to `$caller` but its an error.

[image]
can anyone help?. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

remove single invated comma from query and set them to query it will surely work for you

```
if (empty($_POST['caller'])){ 
    $caller="NULL";
}else{ 
    $caller=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['caller']);
    $caller="'$caller'";
}

$sql_caller = "INSERT INTO `tblcall_info` VALUES ('','$save_inc_id','$call_time','$call_date','$caller','$caller_contact','$receiver','$device')";
```

Comment: its just like my code. it will only generate string null not the actual NULL

Comment: please check my updated comment it may helps you :-|

Comment: as in my statement above in my question i already change `'$caller'` to `$caller` but it generated an error

Comment: i accepted it coz it got me an idea and tried it and it work

Comment: i just put  single quotes in null like this `'NULL'` and remove quotes to `$caller`

Comment: now i got another problem. if the input is not empty it generates an error.

Comment: you need to try my above query there need to add quote when value is not empty. have you problem with no new row inserted right or anything else .. about error (if yes, you can just copy my code it will work with your code)

Comment: Never Mind i got it i just change `$caller=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['caller']);` 
to `$caller="'".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['caller'])."'"; `

Answer (score 1):

Try this method in the $sql_caller string:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,...)  VALUES(value1,value2,...);
```

And skip the column & it's value, which you want to be set as NULL.

Comment: if i skip column and value that i want to be NULL then the problem is if the value is not empty it will not be added to the database. it will always be null even if it is not empty